# shp2pgsql-gui in PostgreSQL9.6 on Cent OS 7

Tags: postgis, postgresql, linux, centos

Using Enterprise DB one click installer available at this [link](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload) for Linux based systems, I have recently installed PostgreSQL 9.6 on my Cent OS 7 (x64) based machine by:

```
su
./binary_file_name
```

Both pgAdmin4 and PostGIS 2.3 works fine. However, I would still like to have GUI based Postgis Shapefile loader. I am unable to find `plugins.ini` file in `/opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/pgAdmin4/plugins` so that I could enable Postgis shapefile loader (shp2pgsql-gui) and `psql` plugins in pgAdmin4 interface. Could anyone point me how to fix this issue?